# What's the pyramid joke?

Tags: discworld, terry-pratchett

In *The Light Fantastic*, after talking about the dimensions of the Pyramid of Tsort, it says

> All in all, it was a lot of effort to go through just to sharpen a razor.

What's the joke here?

Comment: Just like to add that I asked TP this very question at a book signing.  The answers given are very much in line with what he said.

Comment: There was a Donald Duck, many many years ago, with a story about a salesman trying to sell hand-sized Pyramid replica's. One of it's features was indeed sharpening a razor. While I can't find that story (otherwise I'd have made this an answer), I do have [this cartoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZzaQ.png) from a newspaper (*Gadsden Times, November 2 1977*).

Comment: @Mast The Donald Duck cartoon references the same thing, but certainly isn't the originator of the superstition.

Comment: @mattdm Oh, definitely. But it goes to show how well-known Pyramid Power story was. As support to the other answers. TP wasn't the first or the last to make jokes about it.

Comment: I could only find the second half, but here's some background watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja09AO5TocA&t=13s

Comment: I remembered this from telly years ago https://www.stylecraze.com/articles/miraculous-benefits-of-pyramid-meditation-on-your-body/#gref

Comment: I remember cardboard pyramids being put under the beds of small children, to stop them wetting it. Same people who believed in the razor sharpening thing. In the 70s in the Netherlands.

Comment: Interestingly, a similar belief arose on the Discworld, as Sam Vimes is shown to believe that aligning his razor with the Hub keeps it sharp (Men at Arms, one of the later chapters).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In the real world, there is or was a belief, brought on by the Egyptomania of the early 20th century, that [pyramids had special powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_power)—including, specifically, the power to sharpen or maintain the sharpness of razor blades.

> Pyramid power refers to the belief that the ancient Egyptian pyramids and objects of similar shape can confer a variety of benefits. Among these assumed properties are the ability to preserve foods, sharpen or maintain the sharpness of razor blades, improve health, function "as a thought-form incubator", trigger sexual urges, and cause other effects. Such unverified theories regarding pyramids are collectively known as pyramidology.

Czechoslovakian Karel Drbal even [patented a pyramid-shaped device](http://www.amasci.com/freenrg/tors/drbl.html) specifically designed for razor blades. Among the specifications:

> It is beneficial to leave a new blade in the pyramid one to two weeks before using it. It is essential to place it there immediately after the first shave, and not the old, dull one. But it is possible to use an old one, if it is properly resharpened. The blade placed using the method above is left unobstructed until the next shave. The west edge should always face west. It improves the sharpening effect.

Comment: My uncle had a "keeps razors sharp forever" pyramid in (at least) the late 1970s.

Comment: @RonJohn Well? Did it work?

Comment: @pipe he swore it did.  I was more than dubious then (just as I am now), but wasn't going to argue with him about it, in the same way I wouldn't argue religion.

Comment: "Sharped a razor blade, put it in this pyramid, don't use it for 2 weeks - and it'll still be sharp!"

Comment: This was busted on mythbusters: http://kwc.org/mythbusters/2005/06/mythbusters_jetpack_pyramid_po.html

Comment: By the way, the belief that pyramids are magical is still going strong in the real world; see also this question: [About the practical benefit of the electromagnetic discovery in Cheops Pyramid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423782/9077) on Physics.SE

Comment: I don't know the English terms, but pyramid shape is merely one example of general "shape radiation" "theory". It draws not only from Egyptomania, but also tries to explain feng-shui. The radiation kinds are named after colours, and the one emitted by pyramid is "negative green" (because it's on the opposite of actual green). It's probably a problem of terminology because I can't find anything about it on Google. The only thing I could find was some loose connection to "torsion field".

Comment: I distinctly remember pyramid shaped contraptions being sold in the 1980s and into the 1990s that were claimed to prevent wine going bad and turning into vinegar :)

Comment: Alan Parsons Project wrote a song "Pyramania" mocking all the pyramid power claims including the razor bit a few years before The Light Fantastic was published btw

Answer (score 51):

This is a reference to the popular myth that placing a razor blade inside a pyramid shape somehow confers magical powers on it, keeping it sharp, something that that inspired multiple [patents](http://amasci.com/freenrg/tors/drbl.html) in the 1950s.

Interestingly, this does actually work in the world of the Discworld, but not for the reasons you might think. Pyramids cause a slowing (and in extreme cases reversal) of time.

> *By the way, contrary to popular opinion pyramids don’t sharpen razor
> blades. They just take them back to when they weren’t blunt. It’s
> probably because of quantum.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Pyramids by Terry Pratchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramids_(novel))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 19):

This is the legend of 'Pyramid Power'

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_power):

> Pyramid power refers to the belief that the ancient Egyptian pyramids and objects of similar shape can confer a variety of benefits.
>
> Among these assumed properties are the ability to preserve foods, sharpen or maintain the sharpness of razor blades, improve health, function "as a thought-form incubator", trigger sexual urges, and cause other effects.
>
> Such unverified theories regarding pyramids are collectively known as pyramidology.

There is no scientific evidence that pyramid power exists.

Comment: As an additional note: pyramidology often makes a lot of noise about the precise dimensions of the pyramids and how impossibly advanced the measurements are. (In reality, the Egyptians knew what they were doing, and had perfectly serviceable geometry and tools for the task.)

Answer (score 9):

The best resource to find the explanation of jokes in Terry Pratchett books is [the trusty old Annotated Prattchet File on L-Space Web](http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/index.html).  If you look up [the annotations for *The Light Fantastic* in it, and search for "razor"](http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/the-light-fantastic.html#p35), you will find a short explanation there.

> - [p. 35] "He read that its height plus its length divided by half its width equalled exactly 1.67563..."
>
> A parody of the typical numerical pseudo-science tossed about regarding the Great Pyramid and the 'cosmic truths' (such as the distance from the Earth to the Sun) that the Egyptians supposedly incorporated into its measurements.
>
> The remark about sharpening razor blades at the end of the paragraph is similarly a reference to the pseudo-scientific 'fact' that (small models of) pyramids are supposed to have, among many other powers, the ability to sharpen razor blades that are left underneath the pyramids overnight.

Comment: Thanks for the L-Space Link.